# Best practice - use of derived table or use the original table in join?

Tags: teradata, join

Imagine I have the following tables in Teradata :

```
TableA :  Field1|Field2|Field3
TableB :  Field1|Field4|Field5
```

I am trying to join these two tables

Method 1 :

```
SEL TableA.Field3, TableB.Field4
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB
 ON TableA.Field1 = TableB.Field1

WHERE TableB.Field5<>0
```

Method 2 :

```
SEL TableA.Field3, TableB.Field4
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB
   ON TableA.Field1 = TableB.Field1
  AND TableB.Field5<>0
```

Method 3 :

```
   SEL TableA.Field3, TableB.Field4
    FROM TableA 
    LEFT JOIN (
                SEL Field1 ,Field4
                FROM TableB
                WHERE Field5<>0
              ) DTable
    ON TableA.Field1 = DTable.Field1
```

Question : 
I always go for Method 3. But recently my colleague advised it is not the best coding practice as it is using the subquery in join.
Is there anything like a coding standard for joins ?

Comment: Method 1 and 2 are not equivalent.

Comment: What ^^^ @Mihai says. Queries 2 and 3 are equivalent. Query 1 is not.

Answer (score 3):

Your colleague is right.  Method 3's subquery can waste compute.  Therefore use Method 2.

Method 1 and Method 3 do not yield the same results.  The `WHERE` clause in Method 1 performs the filtering after joining the tables.  In effect, it turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Method 2 is equivalent to Method 3 because the `AND` clause performs the filter on TableB before the join (which is what the derived query does).

I created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcc41/1) which illustrates the case.  Full code follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
    Field1 int
  , Field2 varchar(10)
  , Field3 varchar(10)
  );

CREATE TABLE TableB(
    Field1 int
  , Field4 varchar(10)
  , Field5 int);

INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT 0, 'Zero', 'Inner'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'One', 'Inner'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Two', 'Left';

INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT 0, 'Zero', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'One', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Five', 5;

SELECT TableA.Field1
  , TableA.Field2
  , TableA.Field3
  , TableB.Field4
  , TableB.Field5
INTO Method1
FROM TableA
  LEFT JOIN TableB on TableA.Field1 = TableB.Field1
WHERE TableB.Field5 <> 0;

SELECT TableA.Field1
  , TableA.Field2
  , TableA.Field3
  , TableB.Field4
  , TableB.Field5
INTO Method2
FROM TableA
  LEFT JOIN TableB on TableA.Field1 = TableB.Field1
    AND TableB.Field5 <> 0;

SELECT TableA.Field1
  , TableA.Field2
  , TableA.Field3
  , DTable.Field4
  , DTable.Field5
INTO Method3
FROM TableA
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
             FROM TableB
             WHERE TableB.Field5 <> 0) DTable
  on TableA.Field1 = DTable.Field1;

SELECT *
FROM Method1;

SELECT *
FROM Method2;

SELECT *
FROM Method3;
```

Comment: SQL-Fiddle does not have a Teradata option so it's not really a valid proof that derived tables can waste resources.

Answer (score 0):

Teradata's optimizer quite possibly will re-write Method 3 to the same query plan as Method 2. Method 1 will result in an INNER JOIN because the qualification on the `RIGHT` table shouldn't be in the WHERE clause but the ON clause of the `OUTER JOIN` condition. If you were to place an aggregate step such as a DISTINCT or GROUP BY in the derived table of Method 3 you will find the optimizer will likely satisfy the derived table as an individual step without re-writing the plan.

I would suggest that you run the EXPLAIN for each query and compare the output.